# Google Local Cloud Datastore Viewer Not Showing For App Engine Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing an App Engine app in Eclipse with Java. When deploying, I should be able to access the Datastore Viewer at

http://localhost:8081/_ah/admin/datastore

When going to the admin page, I see the datastore link, but clicking it doesn't show the datastore viewer:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCnHr.jpg

I've checked that my gcloud SDK is the latest version, and so too is my Eclipse plugin.

I'm running OSX High Sierra, but have the same issue with Ubuntu.

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Odd as it works for me.  Are there any messages on the console log?  What version of the appengine-api-1.0-sdk are you using?  How did you configure the project?

Comment: I'm using 1.9.59. Stuff of note from logs:  
Dec 19, 2017 3:43:53 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ExtendedLogger warning  
WARNING: The root of the app was not properly defined. Either use a Servlet 3.x container or add an init-param  
jersey.config.servlet.filter.contextPath to the filter configuration. Due to Servlet 2.x API, Jersey cannot determine the request base URI solely from the ServletContext. The application will most likely not work  
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8081/  
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8081/_ah/admin

Comment: (Thanks, I was running into the character limit)

Answer (score 0):

The Datastore Viewer (which is the UI access for the local emulation of Datastore that is available through the Local Development Server), should be accessed through the following link, as stated [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#browsing_the_local_datastore):

http://localhost:8000/datastore

Check that alternative link instead, maybe that was your only issue.

Comment: I think that might be python only, as it 404s for me.

The java equivalent docs seem to suggest the initial URL is right:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server#browsing_the_local_datastore

Comment: Sorry, you were right, the URL I shared was intended for the Python environment, so your Datastore Viewer should appear through the URL you mentioned. I have tried some sample applications in both [Java 7](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/datastore) and [Java 8](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/datastore) myself, and it seems to be working fine for me. Maybe you can try the attached sample applications, extracted from the official repositories, and see if that is working, then adapt your code.